# How can i get n digits from right side in sql

Tags: sql-server

in sql-server how can I get N digits from right side

```
example 123456-->3456
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
123456 % 10000 -- 3456
```

try using [modulo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) or

```
select right(123456,4)
```

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15741)</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

Use `RIGHT()`

```
select right(123456, 4)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/31269)

Comment: This would fail for SQL Server compact and would also involve `cast` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TEST VARCHAR(1000)
SET @TEST = '123456'


SELECT RIGHT(@TEST,4)
```